# Can you have multiple eventNames for Eventbridge terraform event_pattern

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-event-bridge

I'm trying to look out for multiple specific events, can I put multiple eventNames within an array in terraform?

```
     event_pattern = jsonencode({    
      "source": ["aws.lambda"],
      "detail-type": ["CompletedSet"],
      "detail" : {
        "Env": ["${var.environment}"],
        "eventName": ["Event1", "Event2]
        }
    }
```

Is this okay? Or will it cause issues with triggering? Will the rule not trigger unless ALL eventNames are received or will it just look for any that are received? Thanks!

Comment: You should read the details of aws event details as terraform is just a wrapper for the AWS API https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-patterns-arrays.html

Comment: specifically it says `The value of each field in an event pattern is an array containing one or more values. An event pattern matches the event if any of the values in the array match the value in the event.`

Comment: Ok, that helps a lot thank you! I couldn't find anything about it in the terraform docs so was just looking in the wrong place!

Comment: yeah the terraform resource for this attribute just refers you back to AWS https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_event_rule#event_pattern